# Why is my audio playing from inconsistent locations in the mp3 file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-audio-api

I'm trying to play an MP3 from a certain location in milliseconds, but almost every browser plays it from a slightly different spot up to 3-4 seconds in variation.

Firefox seems to be the most accurate, chrome is almost always off.  It really only occurs with longer mp3 files >8 min or so, not shorter ones.

I've tried using many different libraries to play the sound, as well as the web audio API

```js
const audioUrl = "https://lingomastery.s3.amazonaws.com/audio/A0rvqIm27.mp3";
const min = 10;
const sec = 2.2;
const msToPlayFrom = min * 60 * 1000 + sec * 1000;

let sound = new Audio(audioUrl);
sound.currentTime = msToPlayFrom / 1000;
sound.play();
```

Here's a working demo, try in Firefox vs. chrome http://soundtest55.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/

Here's a github repo of that demo https://github.com/dbarker8/sound-test

I expect the audio to play from the same location in each browser, but it starts from different locations in the file.

Comment: Read about the varied precision of `currentTime` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime Every browser has a slightly different threshold for currentTime.